# nodejs fs.rename in a loop (how to use promises correct)

Tags: node.js

i know that my following code will end up in  "Upload of files was not successfull" as successAmount = successAmount+1 will not work because of async behaviour of fs.rename() ... it is clear to use promises here but i dont know how to structure the code in a better way.
My aim is to send status 200, when all files are renamed.
Can you help me with refactoring the code correct, i guess Promise.All() should solve it, but i dont know how ?

```
myMultiFileUploader: async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Entering myMultiFileUploader');

    var successAmount = 0;

    for (let fileItem of req.files) {

        console.log('File '+fileItem);
        console.log('Filename '+fileItem.filename);
        console.log('Mimetype '+fileItem.mimetype);
        console.log('Orig Name '+fileItem.originalname);

        //rename files
        var oldName =""+process.env.FILEUPLOAD_FOLDER+""+fileItem.filename;
        var newName = ""+process.env.FILEUPLOAD_FOLDER+""+fileItem.originalname;

        fs.rename(oldName, newName, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Could not rename uploaded file oldname "+oldName+" to newname "+newName);
            }
            fs.stat(newName, function (err, stats) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Could not rename uploaded file");
            }
            else{
                successAmount = successAmount+1;
            }
            });
        });
    } 

    if(successAmount===req.files.length-1){
        return res.status(200).json({success: 'All Files have been successfully uploaded.'});
    }else{
        return res.status(401).json({error: 'Upload of files was not successful.'});
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used async/await so unnecessary callbacks have been removed. If any file shows error it'll be sent to catch so no need for `successAmount` count. I've attached the updated code below. Hope it helps.

```
const util = require('util');
const stat = util.promisify(fs.stat);
const rename = util.promisify(fs.rename);

myMultiFileUploader: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log('Entering myMultiFileUploader');

        await req.files.map( async (fileItem, index) => {

            console.log('File '+fileItem);
            console.log('Filename '+fileItem.filename);
            console.log('Mimetype '+fileItem.mimetype);
            console.log('Orig Name '+fileItem.originalname);

            //rename files
            var oldName =""+process.env.FILEUPLOAD_FOLDER+""+fileItem.filename;
            var newName = ""+process.env.FILEUPLOAD_FOLDER+""+fileItem.originalname;

            await rename(oldName, newName);
            await stat(newName);
        })
        return res.json({success: 'All Files have been successfully uploaded.'});   
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('Error Occured : '+ err);
        res.status(401).json({error: 'Upload of files was not successful.'});
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Atishay, thanks a lot for your quick reply on this...your code worked well .. the only correction i had to do, was the const util = require('util');
const stat = util.promisify(fs.stat); part ...

I am getting a depectionwarning node:2244) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated ... i guess this is not so critical but any ideas how to "solve" that too ?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the code not much changes just added util.promisify for rename. It won't throw any warning now.

Comment: Although it is still throwing the DeprecationWarning (5xtimes, i guess because of the 5 times loop) this is not so critical for me as you already helped a lot ... thank you so much !

Comment: You're most welcome :). Actually it's showing the warning because we're using async/await instead of callback for `fs` functions. You've updated this line `await fs.rename(oldName, newName);'  to `await rename(oldName, newName);` right?

Comment: You are the best :-) .. yes again you are right with the comment in regards to change fs.rename to rename ... now your answer works like a charm :-) ..

Comment: Happy to help :). #HappyCoding